# Change column width based on another cell value

Tags: excel, vba, macros

In excel, I have two three columns and after transpose I have some change to make. Let the data be ::

```
A   B   C
a   K   .2 
a   Q   .23
a   R   .45
b   L   .3
b   S   .12
c   M   .43
d   N   .54
e   O   .32
f   P   .067

After transpose::
a K Q R
b L S
c M
d N
e O
f P
```

Each row is filled by whatever values I have in column B corresponding to column A. Now the problem is the cell in which I fill K L S Q R i.e. column B values should be of different sized and in ratio of their weight which is column C.For example K should be 0.2, R should be 0.45 or in the same ratio. And since these are written one below the top entire column could not be changed for "a" since the next row cells would be again of different sizes each.

I think this could be achievable by macro but I am not sure about that.Please let me know if you need any further information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean from your wording but it is certainly easy to change column width via vba.

If you want to change column F based on value of C3 then you need:
`Range("F:F").ColumnWidth = Range("C3").Value`

Obviously qualify your range so it's specific to whatever sheet / workbook you want etc.

Comment: I have to change the size of each ad every cell based on their weight which is in column C. Let me know what part confused you?

Comment: I got that your first table had the column reference in Column B and the value in Column C but you then got me confused with Column A and transposing things. I figured your main problem was around column width rather than getting the values so as long as you know where to get the values from the principle should stand.

Comment: But if you look at the example not every column would have a unique width. Each and every cell might have a different width and eventually it would look like a stacked graph horizontally.

Comment: So you're looking at having `B1` having a different width to `B2`? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. I thought may be there is a way to do it. Anyway, can you explain me the Range thingy you did for a unique column width. I am not even able to run that

Comment: As spreadsheets have just two dimensions (up-down & left-right) there's no scope for having different widths for the same column further down. You could work you way round it by having an increasing number of merged cells to cover all your options but that would be massively messy and difficult to maintain. In terms of what I wrote in the answer, I'm presuming you have the VBE open (Alt+F11)? In Project Explorer double-click your sheet, type `Sub test`, hit enter and then in the gap between that and `End Sub` which should appear then paste in `Range("F:F").ColumnWidth = Range("C3").Value`.

Comment: Sorry Tim. Saw your massage late. Yes, I am aware about shortcut and stuffs for vba. I tried that part and was able to get then I thought for a single column if 2 and 4 are the cell widths then for 2 I can get 1 cell and for 4 I can get 2 cells but if the numbers are so many then the LCM would mess it up as you said. Could this formulae be enhanced to apply like a lcm thingy I just want to see how it turns out to be?